# Distributional Assumptions and Bounds of Expectations of Functions involving PDF and CDF

Tags: probability-distributions, definite-integrals, upper-lower-bounds

I am sorry for not being elaborate enough about my earlier question (Jacob Manaker, thank you for letting me know about the clarity issue). Let me try to be more specific and state the complete version of my problem. I am striving to figure out under what type of distributional assumptions the following expression (integrations are taken from the lower bound to upper bounds of a random variable) will be negative or positive.

\begin{equation*}
\frac{2kn-1}{kn\left( kn-1\right) }+\frac{\int F^{kn-2}(z)\ln (F(z))\left(
f(z)\right) ^{2}dz}{\int F^{kn-2}(z)\left( f(z)\right) ^{2}dz}\text{,}
\end{equation*}
where $k\geq 1$ is the scale factor, $n\geq 2$ is the number of players that
are assumed to be identical, and $f(.)$ and $F(.)$ denote the PDF and CDF of
some continuous distribution (possibly supported on a semi-infinite or
infinite interval). I suspect that the answer has something to do with the
hazard rate. In fact, I have established that if the distribution is
exponential (i.e., constant hazard rate), the condition simply takes the
value of zero. Of course, it can be related to other obvious distributional
characteristics, which I may be overlooking.

Note: Please let me know if anything is still unclear. I appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Minor comment: For $F>0$ we get $1 - \frac{1}{F} \leq \log(F) \leq -1 + F$.

Comment: Thank you Micheal for taking the time to comment.